# AWS VPC CIDR range and subnet allocation best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

In my previous job, I was told that when creating a VPC we should always attempt to fill its CIDR as best as possible within its subnets. So a /16 VPC with three public three private subnets,

I got used to setup as:

Public subnets as /20 (in this case /20 x 3) = 12k IPs
Private subnets as /18 (in this case /18 x 3) = ~49.5k IPs

Which would allow for an allocation of 61.5k IPs.

However in my current job, we everyone uses /16 in the VPC and six subnets at /20, which leaves 1/3 of the IP's to be allocated.
In the previous job, VPC peering was a must, as most projects would connect to a main VPC where the e-commerce platform was, in the current job that is not the case, and we don't really have a need to worry about IP collision, which is why no one is really concerned, etc.

The question I have is should we create /16 VPC's for the sake of it (I honestly feel the answer to this should always be no), and should we leave big chunks of IP's unallocated, or should we try to always fill our VPC as best as possible?

My argument to this has always been no to both, because is not a good best practice, but it seems to always go into a mute argument, as the opposite doesn't increase costs.

Comment: You should try to fill them as best as possible and let a few sub-nets be available for future projects/just in case.

Comment: @Overmind thank you. would u say in the first scenario, would u make the subnets at around /20 (public) /19 (private), would u keep it the same (/20 to /18). what sort of percentage of the VPC CIDR do you usually leave unused?

Comment: I don't think of it as percentage. I think of it as maximum available subnet space. Many of my administered areas fit into a /24 which makes things easy, but there are also special devices that only take a few IPs, so therefore I split a /24 into multiple subnets to use for these special devices. That way I waste only one /24 instead of multiple. This is only one example. So in your case, if you can use /19s instead of /18, do so.

Comment: thank you for that. It makes sense your approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim this as best practice, but here's my opinion

- You have virtually unlimited space, so sure, use /16 VPCs. Just don't overlap the CIDR ranges.
- Don't try to fill the IP space inside the VPC, leave some space free for future requirements
- Size subnets for what you need, plus some growth. Remember load balancers can take a fair bit of IP space

**Subnets vs Security Groups**

Here's a bit some will disagree with - especially old school security people, or maybe people who have different use cases from me. I think tiered subnets are not always necessary, and that security groups should be used in place of subnets unless you need a feature that only subnets can provide, such as subnet based routing, servers protected from ingress, NAT. There is a need for public and private subnets, but I don't think "one subnet per application tier" is necessarily the best approach. Services that are not public facing can sometimes get by with one subnet per AZ. Subnets can give "defense in depth" in some cases, which can mitigate against mis-configuration of security groups.

In AWS all subnets in a VPC can route to each other, and you can't change that, but you can use NACLs and security groups to limit communications. However, you may for example want a set of resources that cannot reach the internet or on-premise, or vice versa. You can do this with security groups, but not everyone will trust them. Subnets are appropriate there.

NACLs I tend to use to isolate environments - eg so production resources can't talk to test resources - usually in different accounts but transit gateway enables communications.

When you take this approach you have a small number of larger subnets - maybe only one subnet per AZ, maybe two per AZ to restrict internet access in a way that a security team can accept.

Comment: thank u for ur reply.Your response is little different from overmind, which makes me wonder if there isnt really a "best practice", just "something suits me best". I do disagree a bit with subnets. I have always needed Public and Private subnets, some services wont work in public subnets like KMS (i found this the hard way), i also found that services in the public subnet went automatically through their public IP, as opposed to the Nat GAT EIP (without IPs in route table). There must a lot use cases for ur examples I just never came across them (or have enough experience to know better).

Comment: Agree there is no best practice as such. I'll edit my subnet recommendation to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: KMS works in public subnets. You might want to try a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html), though I'm wondering why you're having trouble with that.

Comment: When was migrating a service (which was in public subnets) to a lambda, the first deployments were made in dev using the same subnets. We couldnt Decrypt with KMS encrypted environment variables within the lambda. After a few hours debugging, we moved the lambda to the private subnets and KMS decrypt requests started working. We actually found a post in stackoverflow where someone had hit the same issue.

Comment: Interesting. I would be a bit careful with the wide statement "KMS doesn't work in public subets", because for example EC2 instances with encrypted volumes work fine in public subnets.

Comment: Oh i didnt know that.... I cant edit my comment though. we always keep everything private (this project was an exception as we inherited it) I kinda want vote for everyone as a correct answer, but i cant. It was really interesting seeing you everyone point of view. I am dev so i get stuck with the same kind of projects most of the time, seeing different takes and views has been really interesting.

Question, while subnets route to each other by default we can lock it, by creating route tables without some subnets right?

Comment: My understanding is all subnets in a VPC can route to each other and that you can't change that, but you can isolate resources with NACLs or security groups

Answer (score 1):

With IPv6, sizing the subsets is solved, all are /64s.

A VPC gets a /56, say it is `2001:db8:9876:5400::/56`. Out of this, perhaps:

- `a` AZ gets  `2001:db8:9876:540a::/64`
- `b` AZ gets `2001:db8:9876:540b::/64`

And so on. These /64s have billions of addresses, and you have 256 of them.  Want a subnet for any reason? Another /64. Globally unique, so no address conflicts.

Route and apply security policy as usual.

---

Your question as asked relates to v4 address planning, with constraints of maximizing utilization and maintaining unique addressing. v6 makes that right-sizing obsolete. The number of hosts doesn't matter.

Of course, after a possibly considerable project to turn it on.

Allocating security related subnets is just one constraint on address plans. But v4 address plans can get complex when you add lots of subnets. That complexity is not there in v6, "public" vs. "private" is all /64s.  Although, see Tim's response for how there is more to security than subnets.

Comment: thank you, never thought about this issue with IPv6, that is pretty neat. And yes i know there is more to security than subnets. Network is such a complex topic. Just wanted to settle this discussion as we kept talking about it at work.